# System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: System.Data.SqlClient: Keyword not supported: 'authentication'

Tags: azure, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I am writing a function to log information from every file uploaded to a blob storage account using entity framework core. When I try to connect to the azure sql db, I get the following error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: BlobStorageLogging. System.Data.SqlClient: Keyword not supported: 'authentication'

I copied my connection string from the azure portal:

> "DefaultConnection": {
>         "ConnectionString": "Server=tcp:dbserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=loggingdb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={*****};
>   MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=\"Active Directory Integrated\";",
>
> "ProviderName": "System.Data.SqlClient"
>       }

The code that is causing the error is:

```
  var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<LoggingDBContext>();
            var options = optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, providerOptions => providerOptions.CommandTimeout(60)).Options;
            using (var context = new LoggingDBContext(options))
            {
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE  [dbo].[BlobInfo]");
```

I have tried removing the authentication but that resulted in an unauthorized error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is expected for now, check the [thread](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8807#issuecomment-441830487).

> SqlClient for .NET Core still does not support using the 'authentication' keyword in the connection string. That will happen when [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8807) is actually fixed.
>
> In order to use AAD in the new version of SqlClient in .NET Core 2.2, customers need to obtain the access token themselves using [ADAL.NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet) and then set the AccessToken property on the SqlConnection

It means in .NET Core, `Active Directory Integrated authentication` is unavailable,  to use `Active Directory password authentication`, we have to obtain access token which seems not ideal in EF configuration.

The workaround is to use Connection string for `SQL authentication`.